# Python: nearest neighbour (or closest match) filtering on data records (list of tuples)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will filter a list of tuples (mimicing an in-memory database), using a "nearest neighbour" or "nearest match" type algorithim.

I want to know the best (i.e. most Pythonic) way to go about doing this. The sample code below hopefully illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
datarows = [(10,2.0,3.4,100),
            (11,2.0,5.4,120),
            (17,12.9,42,123)]

filter_record = (9,1.9,2.9,99) # record that we are seeking to retrieve from 'database' (or nearest match)
weights = (1,1,1,1) # weights to approportion to each field in the filter

def get_nearest_neighbour(data, criteria, weights):
    for each row in data:
        # calculate 'distance metric' (e.g. simple differencing) and multiply by relevant weight
    # determine the row which was either an exact match or was 'least dissimilar'
    # return the match (or nearest match)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = get_nearest_neighbour(datarow, filter_record, weights)
    print result
```

For the snippet above, the output should be:

**(10,2.0,3.4,100)**

since it is the 'nearest' to the sample data passed to the function get_nearest_neighbour().

My question then is, what is the best way to implement **get_nearest_neighbour()**?. For the purpose of brevity etc, assume that we are only dealing with numeric values, and that the 'distance metric' we use is simply an arithmentic subtraction of the input data from the current row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple out-of-the-box solution:

```
import math

def distance(row_a, row_b, weights):
    diffs = [math.fabs(a-b) for a,b in zip(row_a, row_b)]
    return sum([v*w for v,w in zip(diffs, weights)])

def get_nearest_neighbour(data, criteria, weights):
    def sort_func(row):
        return distance(row, criteria, weights)
    return min(data, key=sort_func)
```

If you'd need to work with huge datasets, you should consider switching to [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and using Numpy's [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) to find nearest neighbors. Advantage of using Numpy is that not only it uses more advanced algorithm, but also it's implemented a top of highly optimized [LAPACK (Linear Algebra PACKage)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).

Comment: You can use `min` instead of `sorted` -- it takes a `key` argument as well.

Comment: This is an O(N)-per-query algorithm that is equivalent to the naive algorithm. It will take a very long time for moderately-sized `#points`*`#queries`.

Comment: @ninjagecko: it is, however given that nothing in the question indicates that there would be millions of rows, solutions you propose are premature optimization. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978460/practical-rules-for-premature-optimization)

Comment: @vartec: I am quite aware of premature optimization. People take it as some sort of holy grail. I myself am guilty of using it as a defense. I am not downvoting your answer, merely pointing out that this algorithm is far less efficient than the standard, but *could* work if the *product of the queries times the rows* is less than, say, a million (e.g. 10000 queries and 100 rows), otherwise you will run into issues. If not, the simpler-to-write solution is indeed preferable.

Answer (score 2):

*About naive-NN:*

Many of these other answers propose "naive nearest-neighbor", which is an `O(N*d)`-per-query algorithm (d is the dimensionality, which in this case seems constant, so it's `O(N)`-per-query).

While an `O(N)`-per-query algorithm is pretty bad, you might be able to get away with it, if you have less than any of (for example):

- 10 queries and 100000 points
- 100 queries and 10000 points
- 1000 queries and 1000 points
- 10000 queries and 100 points
- 100000 queries and 10 points

---

*Doing better than naive-NN:*

Otherwise you will want to use one of the techniques (especially a nearest-neighbor data structure) listed in:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search (most likely linked off from that page), some examples linked:

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree
  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing
  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree

especially if you plan to run your program more than once. There are most likely libraries available. To otherwise not use a NN data structure would take too much time if you have a large product of #queries * #points. As user 'dsign' points out in comments, you can probaby squeeze out a large additional constant factor of speed by using the numpy library.

However if you can get away with using the simple-to-implement naive-NN though, you should use it.

Comment: Plus, if speed is a concern, other helpful hacks like using numpy, sqlite3 in-memory databases, cython, or some harmless c-coding can go a long way...

Answer (score 1):

use heapq.nlargest on a generator calculating the distance*weight for each record.

something like:

```
heapq.nlargest(N, ((row, dist_function(row,criteria,weight)) for row in data), operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This is an O(N)-per-query (or worse) algorithm that is equivalent to the naive algorithm. It will take a very long time for moderately-sized `#points`*`#queries`. (If you instantiate a queue with a sorting function and no preprocessing, it must necessarily look at each element, which is at least O(N).) You cannot reuse the queue because the distance function depends on the query point.

Comment: @ninjagecko but it still avoids sorting the whole thing, and gives you more than one nearest neighbor (which `min` can't give you). If I wanted one I would use min of course and not nlargest which is inherently slower. but then how do you know if you have more than one closest neighbor? BTW this data structure might help: http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees

Comment: Whether it actually avoids (effectively) sorting the thing depends on the implementation of `heapq`, mostly on the insertion time. The python documention seems to hint that `heapq` is actually implemented using a binary tree/heap, thus with an insertion time of `O(log(N))`. Thus creating the heap is `O(N log(N))` which is just as bad as sorting. It is possible to, with a better heap implementation, achieve `O(N)` (and a heap is possibly the simplest way to code it). Then again it would be just as cheap to do a linear search k (the 'n' in 'nlargest') times.

Comment: @ninjagecko it's actually more like O(N * log(M)) where N is the size of the data and M is the number of the largest items you want. I tried comparing it to sorted(foo)[:M] which of course does not change based on M, and you can see (besides nlargest being much much faster) that it depends on the size of the heap. I haven't read the C implementation, but I'm sure it's not heapifying the hole list first, it's creating a heap of size M then pushes items to it iteratively while popping others.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting... your analysis seems quite reasonable. Thanks for enlightening me about `heapq.nlargest`'s performance. =) I guess you can just use the standard `heapq` to implement naive-NN; seems the reasonable way to go about doing it.