# If statement processing speed

Tags: optimization, if-statement

This is something simply to ease my curiosity, if someone would feel like answering it though that would be fantastic.

With if statements, is the time taken to calculate the result affected by the way it's written?

So what I mean is (if that wasn't overly clear) would the following two statements take the same amount of time to process?

```
if 1 < 2 and 3 = 3 then
   //do something
end if
```

compared to

```
if 1 < 2 then
    if 3 = 3 then
      //Do something
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Second example is a bad practice and looks ugly

Comment: I'm not sure why this has the java and the .net tag to be honest.

Comment: The questions wasn't language specific, so I put it under the two categories I know. Was just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we consider that the compiler will not optimize these two calls, then the second statement will require two branching instructions instead of one. And branching requires some extra work for the CPU because of pipelining. So, technically, the second version will require more work, but it should not matter here.

Comment: Cool, thanks! If you don't mind answering another questions, do languages such as Java and .net optimize such things?

Comment: @Feash: Java optimizer is pretty smart, but I can't tell you exactly whether it will optimize nested ifs or not. It probably will.

Comment: Naively the first one would require two branches as well, because of short-circuiting.

Comment: @harold: hmm, didn't think about it. Then both cases are equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: There's no branch in this case.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: could you please explain why there would be no branch?

Comment: This case reduces to if(true) if (true) { }; or if (true && true) and finally just to the statement: { }.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen that's only if the compiler does some optimizations and the constants 1, 2 and 3 are *not* meant to be placeholders, and that would just defeat the whole question.

Answer (score 3):

This is just another case of [premature-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2978548/738746). You are not going to gain anything by thinking a lot about this.

What you should be focusing on is how to make your code more readable.

Comment: If you're not answering the question, you should post a comment, not an answer.