# Sorting an NSFetchRequest Based on a Property within a One-to-Many Relationship?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I've been prowling through the SO search results and can't (thus far) find an answer to this question.

Given a data entity A that has a one-to-many relationship to entity B, is there any way to have my NSFetchedResult sort on a *property* of entity B. i.e. Can I have my sort descriptor key drill down into entity B? I've tried dot notation, etc, but nothing is working.

e.g. Entity A has a relationship `inEntityB`. Entity B has a property `entityBproperty`. How can I sort a list of Entity A's based on the `entityBproperty` value of their respective `inEntityB` relationships?

Something like (and no this doesn't work):

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"entityAproperty" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)], 
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"inEntityB.entityBproperty" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)], 
    nil];
```

It seems awfully inefficient to duplicate, in Entity A, the `entityBproperty` that I want to sort by. Isn't the whole point of relationships that you can compartmentalize your data model to keep it more manageable?

Any advice much appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm not really sure what additional information I can add to help clarify the question, but given the lack of response thus far, if anyone has suggestions for what else I might add here, I'm all ears. Unfortunately I don't have bounty privileges yet, or I'd consider one in this case, as this seems like a potentially more obscure question.

Comment: did you find a solution or a work-around to this problem? I have exactly the same situation. Please let me know if you can provide anything helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It seems like there must be a way to do it, though. You may be able to do it using dynamic attributes.

Comment: Are we asking the same question? Here's mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002915/possible-for-an-nssortdescriptor-to-use-a-specific-object-in-a-to-many-relations

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible duplicate of this question [Help sorting an NSArray across two properties (with NSSortDescriptor?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190275/help-sorting-an-nsarray-across-two-properties-with-nssortdescriptor)

Unfortunately it seems like there's no easy way to do this with the dot syntax like you have above.

Comment: The question you've referenced does not seem to be concerned with Core Data. My question, however, is a core data `NSFetchRequest` question at its core (pardon the pun).